# How to find a particular executable file in package?

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to see what a particular funtion does in detail, eg tf static_transform_publisher.
When i use "roscd tf", but get into a dir that contains only a little thing,  "cmake  msg  package.xml  srv". I want to find the executable file or something py srcipy desired, so where is these file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261449/how-to-find-a-particular-executable-file-in-package?/) by [Simon Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/30328/simon-wang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-05-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To expand a bit on Chaos' answer, the packages that you have installed using `apt-get` will be in `/opt/ros/<distro>/lib/`, but source built packages will actually be somewhere else. You can find the location of the executables by running `rospack libs-only-L tf`. This will also work when you have built some packages from source and can be useful when dealing with multiple overlayed workspaces.

As a last point, if you are looking to understand how these libraries work, the executable is probably not the place you want to look and the source, like Chaos mentioned, will be a better place :)

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1